# How to determine if TRUE occurs before FALSE in two columns

Tags: r

I have a list of TRUE/FALSE statements in two columns. I want to determine if a test passes before it fails, a test fails before it passes, or neither. I am trying to create an output for each situation as well.

So for example if a test passes before it fails

```
   Pass  Fail
1  TRUE FALSE
2 FALSE FALSE
3 FALSE FALSE
```

I want the output to say which event occurred and then the row number at which it occurred so for the example above the output would look like this

```
Pass 1
```

Another example of a test that failed

```
   Pass  Fail
1 FALSE FALSE
2 FALSE  TRUE
3  TRUE FALSE
```

The expected output would look like

```
Fail 2
```

And then a situation where there was no pass or fail

```
   Pass  Fail
1 FALSE FALSE
2 FALSE FALSE
3 FALSE FALSE
```

and the expected output would be

```
None 0
```

As I mentioned before, I want to find out which event occurs first.

Pass dataset

```
structure(list(Pass = c(TRUE, FALSE, FALSE), Fail = c(FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE)), row.names = c(NA, 3L), class = "data.frame")
```

Fail dataset

```
structure(list(Pass = c(FALSE, FALSE, TRUE), Fail = c(FALSE, 
TRUE, FALSE)), row.names = c(NA, 3L), class = "data.frame")
```

None dataset

```
structure(list(Pass = c(FALSE, FALSE, FALSE), Fail = c(FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE)), row.names = c(NA, 3L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Is there something like a `test_id` by which these records are grouped?  Or is the entire dataset for a single test?

Comment: @Greg The entire dataset is for a single test

Comment: Good to know.  Also, why not have a single `Result` column, with `TRUE` for "pass", `FALSE` for "fail", and `NA` for "none"?

Comment: @Greg That is a possibility. I was calculating some statistics on the the pass/fail columns but a third Result column could be made

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option relevant for scenarios when only one value is of interest could be:

```
fun <- function(data) {
    ind <- sapply(data, function(x) match(TRUE, x))
    
    if(all(is.na(ind))) {
        setNames(0, "None")
    } else {
        ind[which.min(ind)]
    }
}
```

Results for the first dataset:

```
Pass 
   1
```

second:

```
Fail 
   2
```

third:

```
None 
   0
```

If the output is supposed to be a dataframe, then it could be adjusted to:

```
fun <- function(data) {
    ind <- sapply(data, function(x) match(TRUE, x))
    
    if(all(is.na(ind))) {
        stack(setNames(0, "None"))
    } else {
        stack(ind[which.min(ind)])
    }
}

  values  ind
1      2 Fail
```

Comment: This is really close but for the statistic I want to calculate afterward, I need the output to be a single row with the test result and row number rather than the output being two rows like in your example

Comment: The first solution returns a named vector, but included a solution that returns a dataframe instead :)

Comment: This is really nice for finding one event. Note that you don't even need the `min()` though, as `match(TRUE, x)` is guaranteed to have length 1.

Comment: @Mikko Marttila thanks for pointing that out! I left the min() part there when I was experimenting with something else :D

Comment: **The best solution, IMO.** The code is elegant and the solution is agnostic toward the names and number of columns in `data`.

Comment: @Greg agreed, marked as accepted answer

Comment: @neuron It's trivial, but you could further streamline the code with `sapply(data, match, x = TRUE)`. No anonymous function needed!

Answer (score 2):

A simple **`base`** solution:

## Solution

```
find_result <- function(data) {
  # Make a vector naming the first occurrence of each result.
  firsts <- c("Pass" = which(data$Pass)[1], "Fail" = which(data$Fail)[1])
  
  # If there are no occurrences, default to "None".
  if(all(is.na(firsts)))
    data.frame(Result = "None", Row = 0)

  # Otherwise locate and name the earliest of the two occurrences.
  else {
    which <- which.min(firsts)
    
    data.frame(Result = names(firsts)[which], Row = unname(firsts)[which])
  }
}
```

## Results

Given your sample data reproduced here

```
pass_df <- structure(
  list(
    Pass = c(TRUE, FALSE, FALSE),
    Fail = c(FALSE, FALSE, FALSE)
  ),
  row.names = c(NA, 3L),
  class = "data.frame"
)

fail_df <- structure(
  list(
    Pass = c(FALSE, FALSE, TRUE),
    Fail = c(FALSE, TRUE, FALSE)
  ),
  row.names = c(NA, 3L),
  class = "data.frame"
)

none_df <- structure(
  list(
    Pass = c(FALSE, FALSE, FALSE),
    Fail = c(FALSE, FALSE, FALSE)
  ),
  row.names = c(NA, 3L),
  class = "data.frame"
)
```

the `find_result()` function should yield the following results:

```
#> find_result(pass_df)
  Result Row
1   Pass   1

#> find_result(fail_df)
  Result Row
1   Fail   2

#> find_result(none_df)
  Result Row
1   None   0
```

Answer (score 1):

I’d approach this by first finding the first row where any of the columns in
the input is `TRUE`. Then find the column that is `TRUE` on that row.
A cleverer version uses weighted sums to determine exactly which event(s)
occurred on a row:

```r
find_event <- function(x) {
  # Encode event combination on each row as a binary integer
  codes <- rowSums(2^(col(x) - 1) * x)
  
  # Find first row with any events
  row <- head(which(codes > 0), 1)
  
  # Decode the event combination on that row
  cols <- which(intToBits(codes[row]) > 0)
  events <- colnames(x)[cols]
  
  if (length(events) == 0) {
    data.frame(event = "None", row = 0L)
  } else {
    data.frame(event = events, row = row)
  }
}
```

Tests on the original example data:

```r
pass <- data.frame(
  Pass = c(TRUE, FALSE, FALSE),
  Fail = c(FALSE, FALSE, FALSE)
)

find_event(pass)
#>   event row
#> 1  Pass   1

fail <- data.frame(
  Pass = c(FALSE, FALSE, TRUE),
  Fail = c(FALSE, TRUE, FALSE)
)

find_event(fail)
#>   event row
#> 1  Fail   2

none <- data.frame(
  Pass = c(FALSE, FALSE, FALSE),
  Fail = c(FALSE, FALSE, FALSE)
)

find_event(none)
#>   event row
#> 1  None   0
```

And on some more exotic data:

```r
pass_fail <- data.frame(
  Pass = c(FALSE, TRUE, TRUE),
  Fail = c(FALSE, TRUE, FALSE)
)

find_event(pass_fail)
#>   event row
#> 1  Pass   2
#> 2  Fail   2

indeterminate <- data.frame(
  Pass = c(FALSE, FALSE, TRUE),
  Fail = c(FALSE, FALSE, TRUE),
  Indeterminate = c(TRUE, FALSE, FALSE)
)

find_event(indeterminate)
#>           event row
#> 1 Indeterminate   1
```

Comment: There's probably also a cleverer way to do this, by encoding the column values in `x` so that you could deduce from the row sums which column it was that was `TRUE`.

Comment: I've edited in that cleverer way, also accounting for the possibility of multiple events and generalizing to any number of columns/event types.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an approach using `dplyr::cumany`:

```r
PF <- function(data){

  mymin <- function(x) ifelse(!all(is.na(x)), min(x, na.rm=T), NA)
  
  npass <- sum(cumany(data$Pass))
  firstPass <- mymin(which(data$Pass == T))
  nfail <- sum(cumany(data$Fail))
  firstFail <- mymin(which(data$Fail == T))
  
  if(npass > nfail) c(result = "pass", which = firstPass) else 
    if (npass < nfail) c(result = "fail", which = firstFail) else 
      c(result = "none", which = 0)
}

PF(pass)
result  which 
"pass"    "1"

PF(fail)
result  which 
"fail"    "2" 

PF(none)
result  which 
"none"    "0"
```

Answer (score 1):

##### Solution

```
f <- \(x) c((i <- unlist(mapply(which, x)))[which.min(i)], None = 0)[1]
```

##### Logic

1. For both columns find indices of `TRUE` values using `mapply(which, x)`;
2. Convert to a vector, and assign the result to `i` `(i <- unlist(mapply(which, x)))`. Subset the result by index of minimal value of the result (i.e. occurred first) `(i <- unlist(mapply(which, x)))[which.min(i)]`;
3. Concatenate the result from *step 2* and a vector `c(None = 0)`;
4. Subset the resulting vector by index `1`. Because the resulting vector from *step 3* is always of length `2` (result from *step 2*, and `c(None = 0)`) *except* the case, when *all of the values* in data are `FALSE`. In this case *step 2* will return `integer(0)`. So concatenating `integer(0)` and `c(None = 0)` produces `c(None = 0)`. This way indexing by `1` we always get the right result.

##### Test

```
f(pass)
# Pass 
# 1 
f(fail)
# Fail 
# 2 
f(none)
# None 
# 0
```

##### Drawback

If there are *several* `TRUE` values in the column, the output will change to e.g. `Fail1 1`.

##### Data

```
# success, if there is a fail after that it is not relevant
pass <- structure(list(Pass = c(TRUE, FALSE, FALSE), Fail = c(FALSE, FALSE, FALSE)),
                  row.names = c(NA, 3L), class = "data.frame")
# fail, if there is a success after that, it is not relevant
fail <- structure(list(Pass = c(FALSE, FALSE, TRUE), Fail = c(FALSE, TRUE, FALSE)),
                  row.names = c(NA, 3L), class = "data.frame")
# test never passed or failed
none <- structure(list(Pass = c(FALSE, FALSE, FALSE), Fail = c(FALSE, FALSE, FALSE)),
                  row.names = c(NA, 3L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 1):

### **`purrr` solution:**

```
checker <- function(data){
  check <- unlist(purrr::map(data, which))
  if(purrr::is_empty(check)){
    c('None' = 0)
  } else{
    check[which.min(check)]
  }
}
```

### **Outputs**

```r
Pass 
   1

Fail 
   2 

None 
   0
```